# Importing into a Exported object with MEF

Tags: c#, ioc-container, mef

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked 100 times, but I'm really struggling to get it to work.

Say I have have three projects.

- Core.dll

  - Has common interfaces
- Shell.exe

  - Loads all modules in assembly folder.
  - References Core.dll
- ModuleA.dll

  - Exports Name, Version of module.
  - References Core.dll

Shell.exe has a [Export] that contains an single instance of a third party application that I need to inject into all loaded modules.

So far the code that I have in Shell.exe is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        ThirdPartyApp map = new ThirdPartyApp();

        var ad = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var dircatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".");
        var a = new AggregateCatalog(dircatalog, ad);

        // Not to sure what to do here.
}

class Test
{
    [Export(typeof(ThirdPartyApp))]
    public ThirdPartyApp Instance { get; set; }

    [Import(typeof(IModule))]
    public IModule Module { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create a instance of Test, and load `Instance` with `map` from the `Main` method then load the Module from ModuleA.dll that is in the executing directory then [Import] `Instance` into the loaded module.

In `ModuleA` I have a class like this:

```
[Export(IModule)]
class Module : IModule
{
    [Import(ThirdPartyApp)]
    public ThirdPartyApp Instance {get;set;}
}
```

I know I'm half way there I just don't know how to put it all together, mainly with loading up test with a instance of `map` from `Main`.

Could anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be able to get it to work this way, in the constructor of the Test class(yes I know not to do work in the constructor, I will move it out):

```
public Test()
    {
        ThirdPartyApp map = new ThirdPartyApp();
        this.MapInfoInstance = map;

        //What directory to look for!
        String strPath = AssemblyDirectory;
        using (var Catalog = new AggregateCatalog())
        {
            DirectoryCatalog directorywatcher = new DirectoryCatalog(strPath, "*.dll");
            Catalog.Catalogs.Add(directorywatcher);
            CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();
            batch.AddPart(this);
            CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(Catalog);
            //get all the exports and load them into the appropriate list tagged with the importmany
            container.Compose(batch);

            foreach (var part in Catalog.Parts)
            {
                container.SatisfyImportsOnce(part);
            }
        }

        Module.Run();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main method should probably look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    var exeCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    var dircatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".");
    var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(exeCatalog, dirCatalog);
    var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
    var program = container.GetExportedValue<Program>();

    program.Run();
}
```

To make an instance of the `ThirdPartyApp` class available as a part that can be imported by your modules, you have two options. The first is to explicitly add such an instance to the container with the `ComposeExportedValue` extension method like this:

```
container.ComposeExportedValue<ThirdPartyApp>(new ThirdPartyApp());
```

Alternatively, you can export it via a property by having a class like this one:

```
public class ThirdPartyAppExporter
{
    private readonly ThirdPartyApp thirdPartyApp = new ThirdPartyApp();

    [Export]
    public ThirdPartyApp ThirdPartyApp { get { return thirdPartyApp; } }
}
```